# Prolog: Checking if a sentence begins with a parenthesis

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a clause that checks if a sentence passed into it is (a), so that if I call `factor([(,a,)])`. It will return true

When I have a database with the following clause in it

```
factor --> 
    [(],
    [a],
    [)].
```

I receive the following error

```
?- [db].
ERROR: /Direc/db.pl:2:2: Syntax error: Illegal start of term
true.
```

I am using swi-prolog

Comment: Try putting the parens in quotes: `factor --> ['('], [a], [')'].` And then you don't call `factor([(,a,)])` you would use `phrase(factor, ['(', a, ')']).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your attempt.

The parentheses have a special meaning in Prolog for grouping terms, etc. So if you want to refer to a parenthesis as an atom, you need to put them in quotes.

```
factor --> ['('], [a], [')'].
```

You can write this more clearly as:

```
factor --> ['(', a, ')'].
```

The call `factor([(,a,)])`, or properly written, `factor(['(', a, ')'])` is not the correct way to call your DCG predicate. When defining a DCG, you should call it with `phrase`:

```
phrase(factor, ['(', a, ')']).
```

Which will succeed with the proper definition of `factor//0` above. You could call it as `factor(['(', a, ')'], []).` but using `phrase` is the proper way.